# How to change breakpoint setting in Xcode

Tags: breakpoints, xcode7.3

How to change breakpoint setting in Xcode?

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 I want to change my breakpoint setting.Please check below screen shot.
Let me suggest How can I change setting?

Currently display  breakpoint on Xcode :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOLyV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPOb4.png)

But I need to change n display like below screen

means If I will run code n add breakpoint then display line by line debuerr  same like below screen

Comment: no screenshot, and i don't understand what do you want to achieve

Comment: Please click on :--
enter image description here

Two Screens are available.

Comment: you can not do that, don't go step by step outside of loop or blocks so you will not see that, it is not a breakpoint problem, you are trying to do something weird

Comment: @Shriram Kadam, there are many internal operations while it comes to blocks and may be loops. step by step will go to those operations. Try to use multiple breakpoints instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to Breakpoint Navigator like in here -

[image: Navigator]

and at bottom you'll find a '+' symbol. There you can find few options, say 'Add Exception Breakpoint'..

[image]

You can select these for a breakpoint.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Satish , but still facing this issue.